# Why am I getting errors with my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I am trying to practice JavaScript with basic DOM manipulation but I keep getting 2 errors:

> 1.SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
>
> 2.TypeError: size is not a function

```js
function size() {
  var height = document.body.getElementById('hover1').style.height: 500 px;
  var width = document.body.getElementById('hover1').style.width: 500 px;
}
console.log(hover);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>javascript practice</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 7em auto;
      background-color: green;
      width: 90%;
    }
    
    #size1 {
      background-color: blue;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      margin: 3em auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="size1"></div>
  <input type="button" value="size" onclick="size();">
</body>
```

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Answer (score 2):

your error is here:

```
var height = document.body.getElementById('hover1').style.height: 500px;
var width = document.body.getElementById('hover1').style.width: 500px;
// -------------------^  and -------------------------------------^
```

replace those lines with these:

```
var height = document.getElementById('hover1').style.height;
var width = document.getElementById('hover1').style.width;
```

Comment: document.body.getElementById is not correct it should be document.getElementById

Comment: @assembler, welcome to SO. Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how the site works. "Thank you" comments are discouraged.

Comment: @Rob can you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called `document.body.getElementById` instead change this to `document.getElementById` use as below

```
var height = (document.getElementById('hover1'))?document.getElementById('hover1').style.height: "500px";
var width = (document.getElementById('hover1'))?document.getElementById('hover1').style.width: "500px";
```

```js
function size1() {
console.log("test")
var height = (document.getElementById('hover1'))?document.getElementById('hover1').style.height: "500px";
var width = (document.getElementById('hover1'))?document.getElementById('hover1').style.width: "500px";

 }



    //console.log(hover);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>javascript practice</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<style>

  body {
    margin: 7em auto;
    background-color: green; 
    width: 90%;
  }

  #size1 {
    background-color: blue; 
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 3em auto;
  }

</style>
  </head>
  <body>

<div id="size1">



</div>

   <input type="button" value="size" onclick="size1()">

   </body>
```

Comment: This doesn't run.

Comment: @Rob what you mean..?

Comment: You are correcting him to remove body from `document.body.getElementById` but there is nothing wrong, technically, with using body in that.

Comment: chrome and as per MDN body is an element itself so it doesn't have getElementById function defined.you can't access it in chrome..as well..

Comment: try running here in the snippet it will work..if you are getting errors then paste what error it is..

Comment: @Matt check now i have updated for size it should work

Comment: Yes but that doesn't make it an error or mean it won't work.

Comment: @Rob how and i'm not sure if i understand your point...body.getElementById with will not work as function doesn't exists on body element...

Comment: I never said it would and I did not say to use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to set the height of the element and assign the height to `var height` then you need to do the following:

```
var height = document.getElementById("size1").style.height = "500px";
```

If you are going to just assign the height of the element to `var height` then you need to do the following:

```
var height = document.getElementById("size1").style.height;
```

If you are just going to set the height of the element then you just need to do:

```
document.getElementById("size1").style.height = "500px";
```

You should also make your `500px` with quotes as numbers do not need `" "` around them but once you add text...it all becomes text. So either way you should have `"500px"`

I would also make your button into this:

```
<button type="button" value="size" onclick="size()">Size</button>
```

Based on a belief that you are trying to make the div larger onclick of `Size` button then you should have the following:

Style

```
body {
    margin: 7em auto;
    background-color: green;
    width: 90%;
}

#size1 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 3em auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="size1"></div>

<button type="button" value="size" onclick="size()">Size</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function size() {
  document.getElementById('size1').style.height = "500px";
  document.getElementById('size1').style.width = "500px";
}
```